# rigthmost menu setting menu

Tags: android, android-layout

In some application I have seen the rightmost menu place on some application, labeled as X at below sketch. How can I create those menus and how can I reach them ? Is it related with layout ? In other words, should I skecth manually these layout and add button to it ?

```
----------------------------------------------
|                                    |   <X> |
|--------------------------------------------|
|                                            |
|                                            |
|                                            |
|                                            |
|                                            |
|                                            |
|                                            |
|                                            |
|                                            |
----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of menu can be implemented using ActionBar follow this link...

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

however you can create your own layout to implement the menu, it should not be so difficult.